# Getting JSON callback not working

Tags: jquery, json

I want to use this api that returns the place matching a zipcode

e.g. for zip 11233

```
http://postnummersok.se/api?q=11233
```

I call it with a user input value like this but the result does not parse, how can I troubleshoot, is it even getting the callback? My firebug shows no js errors.

```
$('#zip').live("keyup",function () {
    var zip = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
    if(zip.length > 4) {
        var url = 'http://postnummersok.se/api?q=' + zip;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    } else {
         $('#result').html('to short');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the document your code is in is not on `http://postnummersok.se`. If it isn't, you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which doesn't (normally) allow ajax requests to cross origins.

If this is a publicly-available service, they probably support [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), which is not subject to the SOP. jQuery also supports it, so it may be as easy as changing your code from this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
});
```

to this

```
$.ajax({
    url:      url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:  function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

More in the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs.

---

**Update**: Noticed when commenting on another answer that you're dynamically creating a query string, but not encoding the parameter. If `zip` contains any characters that have to be URL-encoded, your URL will be messed up. Whenever creating query strings, you have to use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var url = 'http://postnummersok.se/api?q=' + encodeURIComponent(zip);
```

...or just pass an object with key/value pairs to jQuery, which will serialize them correctly for you. Here's what that would look like, modifying my ajax call above:

```
$.ajax({
    url:      'http://postnummersok.se/api',
    data:     {q: zip},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:  function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

---

**Update 2**: I got curious, and yes, you are allowed to use this service, and yes it uses JSON-P. From http://postnummersok.se/:

> **API**
>
> Vi har ett rest-api tillgängligt för alla.
>   Skicka din sökfråga till http://postnummersok.se/api med parametern q som antingen är ett postnummer eller en ort. Svaret kommer som ett JSON-objekt. Callback-parametern heter callback.

...which Google translates as

> **API**
>
> We have a residual-api available to all.
>   Send your query to http://postnummersok.se/api with parameter q which is either a postcode or place. The answer comes as a JSON object. The callback parameter named callback.

However, the service is broken and returning invalid JSON-P replies. If you send it

```
http://postnummersok.se/api?callback=myCallback&q=721+06
```

...the response is

```
myCallback(["V\u00c4STER\u00c5S"])myCallback(null)
```

...where it should be

```
myCallback(["V\u00c4STER\u00c5S"])
```

(Possibly with a `;` at the end.)

So I'd drop them a note about the bug if I were you.

Comment: can I ajax call a php that handles and parse the callback to solve this?

Comment: @Joseph: If the service you're calling is really public (meant for others to use), then the above probably works. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I have tried, when putting on Firebug I got a new error message `uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x90570008 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://mysite.com/js/jquery.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 3" data: no]`

Comment: @Joseph: Yeah, I just tried it and updated the answer. The service is broken.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will contact them

Comment: found this http://yourmoneyisnowmymoney.com/api/ and see, with your example (exchanging only the param name and url), in firebug that the response is received successfull but getting the 'invalid label' error msg, with `json`I get no response at all.

Comment: @Joseph: That API page doesn't say it supports JSON-P, just JSON. Unless they're implementing [cross-origin resource sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and they're not, I checked) and you're using a browser that supports it, you'll hit the SOP I mentioned in my answer. Please do have a read through that page on the SOP, and a read through the JSON-P link as well so you understand the difference between JSON (a data format) and JSON-P (a means of using that data format that works around the SOP).

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a AJAX, but JSONP.

You could do it like this:

```
$('#zip').live("keyup",function () {
    var zip = this.value.replace(/ /g,'');
    if(zip.length > 4) {
        var url = 'http://postnummersok.se/api?callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, { q: zip },
            function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
        });
    } else {
         $('#result').html('to short');
    }
});
```

Note that I've added "callback=?" to the URL so jQuery will know it's JSONP, and moved `zip` to the `data` parameter of the call. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for details.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a bit of explanation, correcting the code formatting, and removing the `+ zip` at the end of the `var url` line (since you're supplying it in the `data` parameter).

Comment: the code makes the call in addition to using "json" but the result is not parsed, how can I troubleshoot? Also the docs say that the Callback parameter is called `callback`but neither `data` or `data.callback`parse anything